# Strapi using conditional _in in find()

Tags: node.js, strapi

In my case I am using **event_type_in: filter_by** in find condition. now if we pass the **filter_by** array empty I want to return all the results otherwise only those passed in filter_by

```
searchEvents: async (ctx) => {
    try {
      const {
        title='',
        filter_by=[],
        sort = 'date',
        start = 0,
        limit = 6
      } = ctx.request.body;

      const events = await strapi.services['events'].find({
        title_contains: title,
        event_type_in: filter_by,
        _start: start,
        _limit: limit,
        _sort: sort
      });

      const response = events.map((r) => {
        r = sanitizeEntity(r, { model: strapi.models['events'] });
        delete r.event_type.created_at;
        delete r.event_type.updated_at;
        delete r.event_type.published_at;
        delete r.created_at;
        delete r.updated_at;
        return r;
      });

      ctx.send({ events: response });
    } catch (error) {
      ctx.badRequest(error.message);
    }
  }
}
```